# FragmentStatePageAdapter doesn't remove child fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter, fragmentmanager

Having a problem with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and screen change orientation (saving state I guess).
The layout of my app is the following:

```
Activity -->
         Fragment A
         Fragment B (contains a FragmentStatePagerAdapter) wich shows 2 fragments 
                  --> 
                    Fragment B1 
                    Fragment B2
```

All the fragments mentioned inherit from a `BaseFragment` class that doesn't do anything special but keeping some "global" vars I need.
When `Activity` starts loads up `Fragment A`. From a menu I replace `Fragment A` with `Fragment B`. `Fragment B` source is the following:

```
public class Fragment B extends BaseFragment {

    public static String TAG = "b_fragment";
    private MyCustomPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new MyCustomPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        //adapter = new MyCustomPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        tags.add(FragmentB1.TAG);
        tags.add(FragmentB2.TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);        
    }

    class MyCustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    //class MyCustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        FragmentManager mgr;
        public SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

        public PrepagatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager mgr) {
            super(mgr);
            this.mgr = mgr;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new FragmentB1();
                case 1:
                    return new FragmentB2();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)  {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment)  super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            registeredFragments.remove(position);
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        }

        public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
            return registeredFragments.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem happens when I go to `Fragment B` then go back again to `Fragment A` and change orientation: I see while debugging on the `onAttach()` method of `Fragment A` that in the `FragmentManager` `Fragment B` is no more present (replaced by `Fragment A`) but `Fragment B1` and `B2` are there and are called their rispective `onAttach()` methods, resulting in weird behaviours of the layout. Didn't the child fragments should be remove from the `FragmentManager`?

At the moment I don't know if more details are needed. I can give further if you need.